# Undefined method for class - Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

It seems I don't quite understand initializing or using a class within another class.

I have a Sinatra app and have created a class to handle fetching data from an api

```
# path: ./lib/api/bikes/bike_check
class BikeCheck
  def self.check_frame_number(argument)
    # logic here
  end
end
BikeCheck.new
```

I then have another class that needs to consume/use the `check_frame_number` method

```
require 'slack-ruby-bot'
# Class that calls BikeCheck api
require './lib/api/bikes/bike_check'

class BikeCommands < SlackRubyBot::Bot
  match /^Is this bike stolen (?<frame_number>\w*)\?$/ do |client, data, match|
    check_frame_number(match[:frame_number])
    client.say(channel: data.channel, text: @message)
  end
end
BikeCommands.run
```

When `check_frame_number` is called I get a `undefined method` error. What I would like to know is what basic thing am I not doing/understanding, I thought by requiring the file which has the class it would be available to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not require a method defined in class - methods defined in class only available to class, class instances and within the inheritance.

Mixing method only possible with including modules.

To solve you issue you could either do

```
class BikeCommands < SlackRubyBot::Bot
  match /^Is this bike stolen (?<frame_number>\w*)\?$/ do |client, data, match|
    BikeCheck.check_frame_number(match[:frame_number]) # <===========
    client.say(channel: data.channel, text: @message)
  end
end
```

or write a module with the method and `include`/`extend` in class, you want that method to be available in.

Comment: thank you for clearing that up. Is there a preferred way, so module or call the class as you have specified ?

Comment: It usually depends on the situation, I use both. But here if you defined `BikeCheck` only to contain a method you want to use in `BikeCommands` - it definitely qualifies as a case to use module instead :)

Comment: thanks again, when inlcuding/extending I can just call the method by name then?

Comment: @Richlewis right. When method is mixed in you can use it by name :)

Comment: so i've changed my class to a module, removed `BikeCheck.new` and then within `BikeCommands` class I have `include BikeCheck`. but still get same error, if you could provide a module example that would help a lot, thanks

Comment: remove `self` from `check_frame_number` method definition, add `extend BikeCheck` in `BikeCommands` and of course `require` the file with module at the top. It would work, the only thing is that you defined `check_frame_number` to not accept any arguments, but are passing `match[:frame_number]`..

Comment: ah i see, sorry that was a typo with not accepting an argument